# PHP always show 3 li elements even if while loop test expression is false

Tags: php, html, loops, layout

I'm looking for a nice solution to always show a set number of elements - in this case 3 - even if the while loop test expression is false.

This is to get a uniform grid layout, so that I don't need to mess around with equal height columns etc...

**CODE**

```
<ul class="event__lineup">
    <?php 

    $l = 0;

    while ( has_sub_field('event_lineup') ) :

        echo '<li class="title" itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">' . get_sub_field('event_artist') . '</span></li>';

        if ( $l == 2 ) : break; endif;

    $l++;

    endwhile;

    ?>
</ul>
```

I'm looking to use a placeholder if say there's only 1 artist or 2:

```
echo '<li class="title">&nbsp</li>';
```

I understand a while loop maybe isn't the best solution, however, I'm not sure how to approach a different solution.

**EDIT**

```
<ul class="event__lineup">
    <?php

    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        if ( has_sub_field('event_lineup') ) {
            echo '<li class="title" itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">' . get_sub_field('event_artist') . '</span></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li class="title">&nbsp</li>';
        }
    }

    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul class="event__lineup">
<?php

$done = false;

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    if (!has_sub_field('event_lineup')) {
        $done = true;
    }

    if ($done) {
        echo '<li class="title">&nbsp</li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li class="title" itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">' . get_sub_field('event_artist') . '</span></li>';
    }
}

?>
</ul>
```

The `for` loop will execute 3 times regardless of the results of the call to `has_sub_field`.  It appears - based on the results you were getting in your initial testing - that once `has_sub_field` returns `false`, the next call to `has_sub_field` will reset its internal index and it will start over from the beginning.

So we set `$done` to `true` the first time that `has_sub_field` returns `false` and then use `$done` to decide when we print the sub field and when we print the placeholder `<li>`.

Comment: This works apart from when there's 1 artist and then it repeats artist 1 in position 3??? So, Artist 1 - Placeholder - Artist 1??

Comment: I looked at using a for loop and couldn't figure it out, rookie error

Comment: Nice... you worked that out far too quickly :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Good explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

Placing this after your Loop should check how many elements are missing to reach the minimum number to show and echo the correct number of placeholders:

```
$minimumNumberToShow = 3;
if($l < 3){
  for($i; $ < ($minimumNumberToShow-$l);; $i++){
    echo '<li class="title">&nbsp</li>';
  }
}
```